# Wordpress - customized pages with blocks - prohibit google seo index of blocks

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, seo, robots.txt, xml-sitemap

I'm using Wordpress and WooCommerce for my online shop.
With the theme I'm using you can customize the product-category pages by adding "blocks".

So if I want to have a text on the top of a product category page I simply create a block page, lets say its called "category-info". 
I can customize this block just as a normal Wordpress page. 
The block will be availabe under http://example.com/block/category-info/ - but nobody will access the block site by it self because this block gets integrated in a product category page.

Finally I can fill in the name of the block in my product category settings and after this the content of the block will be shown on the product category page.

**My question is what should I do in order to avoid that Google and other search engines index those "block pages" itself?** Should I deny the access in the robots.txt or the xml sitemap ect? It's very important that the content of the block, which you can see on the product-category page - still gets indexed and crawled from google - just the direct link to a stand-alone block page should get removed.
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Hey, regarding your style of question: when asking / answering by using very much text it would be helpful to **highlight the main keywords and the question**. You may want to think of that while editing your question and asking / answering in the future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noindex tags would be useful. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=en

Comment: That sounds great, thank you! If I use this tags, will Google still craw the content (text ect.) ?

Comment: Yes, google will crawl but the pages wont be indexed.